# facebook open graph for iOS error during publishing

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-opengraph, publishing

I am trying to submit what I think is a pretty basic open graph post on facebook in iOS7. I am using the latest version of everything, including facebook's SDK version 3.10.

My app brings up the share dialog preloaded with the parameters from my `FBGraphObject`.  I even had an image URL in there earlier that shows in the preview, just took it out trying to troubleshoot. I type a few words in the "Say something about this..." part of the share dialog and tap "Post." This is the error I get:

> Error Domain=com.facebook.Facebook.platform Code=102 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.Facebook.platform error 102.)" UserInfo=0x19192ba0 {error_message=An error occurred during publishing., app_id=299416296871047, error_code=102}

I can't seem to find another question with this same error. Here is my code:

```
id<FBOpenGraphAction> action = (id<FBOpenGraphAction>)[FBGraphObject graphObject];
        NSMutableDictionary<FBGraphObject> *object =
        [FBGraphObject openGraphObjectForPostWithType:@"og.item"
                                                title:@"Test Post"
                                                image:nil
                                                  url:@"https://mywebsiteurl.com"
                                          description:@"A test post"];
        [action setObject:object forKey:@"something"];

[FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithOpenGraphAction:action
                                              actionType:@"og.publish"
                                     previewPropertyName:@"something"
                                                 handler:^(FBAppCall *call, NSDictionary *results, NSError *error) {
                                                     if(error) {
                                                         NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.description);
                                                         NSLog(@"Results: %@", results);
                                                     } else {
                                                         NSLog(@"Success.");
                                                     }//end if
                                                 }];
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. It turned out to be permission issue. Facebook user that that I used to post OG story wasn't administrator or the developer in the Facebook app roles and permissions.

In order to use it with any user your app has to be reviewed by Facebook.

Comment: I would like the source as well. It's surprising that this is not more clearly stated on the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. What's the size of the OG object in the URL?
Mine was rather large and the Facebook app was not waiting long enough to complete the post.

At the moment i'm publishing successfully via `FBRequestConnection startForPostWithGraphPath`

```
// create object
id<FBOpenGraphAction> action = (id<FBOpenGraphAction>)[FBGraphObject graphObject];
[action setObject:url forKey:@"something"];
[action setObject:@"true" forKey: @"fb:explicitly_shared"];

[FBRequestConnection startForPostWithGraphPath:@"me/og.item"
                                   graphObject:action
                             completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
}];
```

Make sure the 'Explicitly Shared' option for this action type is enables in the App Dashboard.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I realize this was a long time ago but I didn't have the rep points to respond at the time. I believe my issue was not setting the story/OG object up correctly on the Facebook side. I just moved on to other parts of the project and hoped the documentation would improve by the time I got back around to it. Luckily, it has. If anyone finds their way here, check this out: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/open-graph/